# Query fields in google contacts REST API

Tags: google-contacts-api, jsonparser

I am trying to build a bash scripts to manage my google contacts programatically using the google contacts api. From the api-reference I can see the rest api to list full/single contacts entry in xml or json format. But I cannot able see any filter option to fetch name, mobile number alone.

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full?alt=json`

Response:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "entry": {
        "id": {
            "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/base/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2019-03-16T02:56:27.686Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "$t": "NEW_CONTACT_NAME",
            "type": "text"
        },
        "link": [
            {

            }
        ],
        "content": {
            "$t": "Tets Entry!",
            "type": "text"
        },
        "gd$organization": [
            {
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                "gd$orgName": {
                    "$t": "javis"
                }
            }
        ],
        "gd$email": [
            {
                "address": "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
            }
        ],
        "gd$phoneNumber": [
            {
                "label": "Prime",
                "uri": "tel:+xx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
                "$t": "+xx xxxxx xxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "gContact$groupMembershipInfo": [
            {
                "deleted": "false",
                "href": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/xxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/base/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$batch": "http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch",
        "xmlns$gContact": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008",
        "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"
    }
}
```

Could you please help me to find the solution to filter specific field like contact id, name, number or mail from the json response.

Comment: You're given the full object, just pull out the data you want. Do you have a technical requirement to save a couple hundred bytes of bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to filter but it is not working and getting the INVALID_ARGUMENT error saying `Error expanding 'fields' parameter. Cannot find matching fields for path 'version'.` for the below query. **`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/531c64be8e85acbd?fields=version&alt=json`**